# How to use graph.openManagement().updateIndex()?

Tags: janusgraph

I have janusgraph database, in which all indexes were built.But the status of some of those indexes is installed. Now I am trying to update those Indexes to the registered and then to enabled. So I have done some research and I found this [Action(schemaAction)](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-management/index-lifecycle/).But I don't know the syntax and also how to use `graph.openManagement().updateIndex()`.

Any suggestions regarding this issue or if there is anything other than this procedure, then please let me know it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byNameUnique"), SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get() is for getting the status?

Comment: I have used this `mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("giftIdByGift"), SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get()` but ended up with an error 
The vertex or type is not associated with this transaction [giftIdByGift]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any open transactions while creating the indexes they might get stuck in the INSTALLED state.
You can find a clear explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373081/8503505).
After rolling back your open transactions and closing open instances, try reindexing.

**Note:** Block until the SchemaStatus transitions from INSTALLED to REGISTERED, after running the reindex command. Try to run groovy script instead of running the commands directly on gremlin console for building the indexes. Please find the sample script below.

```
import org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem

mgmt = graph.openManagement();
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("giftIdByGift"), SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "giftIdByGift").call();
mgmt.commit();

mgmt = graph.openManagement();
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("giftIdByGift"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "giftIdByGift").status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call();
mgmt.commit();
```